# Straight on board 10 j q k a who wins?

Tags: rules

the straight is, 10 j q k a

player A has king ace

player B has 2 3

who wins? is it split pot?

Comment: play the board and split

Answer (score 0):

The best combination of 5 cards out of 7 wins. So the best combination is on the board (which is Straight) for both players.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what the suits are.  If the Q J 10 on the board are all of the same suit, and Player A has AJ suited of that same suit, then Player A has a royal flush which beats Player B, who is playing the board with an ace high straight.  Otherwise, the best hand both players can make is an Ace high straight and it's a chop.